# Mysql - unchangable table after adding a ENUM field

Tags: mysql, enums

I added a `ENUM` column in a table using `Phpmyadmin`. Just a simple field (4 values, 1 default). The table has a bunch of elements but it worked fast before.

There is two problems now:

1. `Phpmyadmin` won't let me see 'Structure' tab now. It just 'ignores' click on that tab. But it seems that it doesn't freeze.
2. When I try to make some changes in the table, it doesn't apply. There is no errors but there is no result.

If I `DROP` this new `COLUMN` table works just fine.

I thought that `ENUM` is a fast type...

Comment: Are you sure that your inserting operation was finished?

Comment: You enter the Land of the Bizarre when using enums. Then again, you are already there.

Comment: There a good thing that I can use instead of ENUMs?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `ENUM`.  The same can't necessarily be said of PMA.

Comment: I can tell ya a ton wrong with ENUMs. Is there a good thing to use instead of enums? How about normal datatypes.